# How to make a good graph with this dataset in julia language?

Tags: julia, visualization, vega-lite, julia-plots

I have got this dataset in julia:

```
julia> import Downloads

julia> using DLMReader, VegaLite, InMemoryDatasets

julia> data=Downloads.download("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/akshdfyehd/salary/main/ds_salaries.csv");
 
julia> ds=filereader(data,emptycolname=true);

julia> new=filter(ds,:employment_type,by= ==("FT"));

julia> select!(new,:job_title,:salary_in_usd,:work_year)
588×4 Dataset
 Row │ job_title                   work_year  experience_level  salary_in_usd
     │ identity                    identity   identity          identity
     │ String?                     Int64?     String?           Int64?
─────┼────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
   1 │ Data Scientist                   2020  MI                        79833
   2 │ Machine Learning Scientist       2020  SE                       260000
   3 │ Big Data Engineer                2020  SE                       109024
   4 │ Product Data Analyst             2020  MI                        20000
   5 │ Machine Learning Engineer        2020  SE                       150000
   6 │ Data Analyst                     2020  EN                        72000
   7 │ Lead Data Scientist              2020  SE                       190000
   8 │ Data Scientist                   2020  MI                        35735
   9 │ Business Data Analyst            2020  MI                       135000
  10 │ Lead Data Engineer               2020  SE                       125000
  11 │ Data Scientist                   2020  EN                        51321
  12 │ Data Scientist                   2020  MI                        40481
  13 │ Data Scientist                   2020  EN                        39916
  14 │ Lead Data Analyst                2020  MI                        87000
  ⋮  │             ⋮                   ⋮             ⋮                ⋮
 576 │ Data Analytics Manager           2022  SE                       150260
 577 │ Data Analytics Manager           2022  SE                       109280
 578 │ Data Scientist                   2022  SE                       210000
 579 │ Data Analyst                     2022  SE                       170000
 580 │ Data Scientist                   2022  MI                       160000
 581 │ Data Scientist                   2022  MI                       130000
 582 │ Data Analyst                     2022  EN                        67000
 583 │ Data Analyst                     2022  EN                        52000
 584 │ Data Engineer                    2022  SE                       154000
 585 │ Data Engineer                    2022  SE                       126000
 586 │ Data Analyst                     2022  SE                       129000
 587 │ Data Analyst                     2022  SE                       150000
 588 │ AI Scientist                     2022  MI                       200000
                                                              561 rows omitted
```

I have tried following graph:
[image]

[image]

But these are not really represent the info quite clearly, because I don't have quite good ideas about how to visualize these info now, this graph is a good one but I'm not sure if my dataset can produce this kind of graph:
[image]
can I please have any sugesstions to make a better graph? any other packages as long as it can show good graph.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you please specify how you would like the visualization to look? There are excellent ecosystems like Plots.jl or Makie.jl apart from the VegaLite.jl you can try.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I have already edit my question.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest you read the following to get a good idea of better dataviz practices.

https://clauswilke.com/dataviz/

In answer to your question, it really depends what you're trying to show. In the first instance, I would switch the axes and that will make the data a lot more readable.